# R limma alternatives in Python

Tags: r, python, differential-expression, limma

The R package [`limma`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html) is ideal to perform differential expression analysis. Is there any `limma` alternative in Python?

I'm trying to use [`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) and [`scikitlearn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) in conjunction with some other cool tools (such as [`pycombat`](https://github.com/epigenelabs/pyComBat)) to get `limma`-like workflows. However, I'm missing many capabilities from the `limma` toolbox.

Comment: Is there a possibility for you to call R from Python? If so you can try Rpy2 (https://pypi.org/project/rpy2/)

Comment: That's true. You can always wrap Python around R. For example, if working with `limma`, you can use Python to prepare the pieces that `limma` needs to create an Expression Set object with the `ExpressionSet()` function (expression, phenotype and feature data). However you will be always forced to write the `limma` workflow using R syntax. In any case I will give it a try! Many Thanks!

Comment: I am working on EXACTLY this thing. My `methylize` python package supports some of these functions, but I found this while looking for packages that might give me idea about what features people want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**August 2021**

To date, it seems that the response to this question is **"No"**. However, there is a GitHub repository called [`edgePy`](https://github.com/r-bioinformatics/edgePy), aiming to *"become an implementation of [`edgeR`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/edgeR.html) for differential expression analysis in the Python language"* (`edgeR` is somewhat similar to `limma`).

PS: Many thanks to @ATpoint90 (the Twitter ["hive mind" summoner](https://twitter.com/ATpoint90/status/1423669033702940678)) and @sridnona6 (`edgePy` developer).